# How to represent denormalized tables in R?

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

Given hierarchical data, such as the following:

```
nodes <- data.frame(node_id=c(1,2,3),node_label=c('a','a','b'))
arcs <- data.frame(arc_id=c(1,2),from_node_id=c(1,2),to_node_id=c(2,3))
```

What would be the closest solution in `R` to the following `SQL VIEW`?

(So **not** just a new data.frame, but also the mechanism which ensures data integrity as in an `SQL VIEW`)

```
CREATE VIEW AS
SELECT
    arcs.*,
    from_node.node_label,
    to_node.node_label
FROM
    arcs
    JOIN nodes AS from_node ON
        arcs.from_node_id = from_node.node_id
    JOIN nodes AS to_node ON
        arcs.to_node_id = to_node.node_id;
```

Or as a better definition, how would the following `merge()` be possible without loops or temporary variables?

```
merge(arcs,data.frame(label='e'),by.x='from_node_label',by.y='label')
```

What I have tried:

- If I am trying to access these two data frames directly such as the following, many matrix operations become loops.

  ```
  nodes[nodes$node_id=arcs[i,]$from_node_label,]
  ```
- If use nested data frames such as `arcs$from_node <- node[c(1,2),]`, this looks very promising but data needs to be manually updated and it still does not allow for merging like

  ```
  > merge(arcs,data.frame(label='e'),by.x='from_node$label',by.y='label')
  Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid column(s)
  ```
- Finally, I am using the following two functions to expand the data frame to a denormalized "view" and collapse it when done. The only problem with this that I still manually have to guarantee that the affected columns don't change while the data frame is "expanded".

  ```
  expand_arcs <- function(nodes,arcs) {
      from_nodes <- nodes
      names(from_nodes) <- paste('from',names(from_nodes),sep='_')

      to_nodes <- nodes
      names(to_nodes) <- paste('to',names(to_nodes),sep='_')

      arcs <- merge(merge(
          arcs,
          from_nodes),
          to_nodes)

      return(list(nodes,arcs))
  }

  collapse_arcs <- function(nodes,arcs) {
      arcs <- arcs[c('arc_id','from_node_id','to_node_id')]

      return(list(nodes,arcs))
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

you can transalte you code in sql but the easier is to use `sqldf` package since you seems comfortable with sql

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT   arcs.*, from_node.node_label, to_node.node_label
       FROM  arcs
       JOIN nodes AS from_node 
            ON arcs.from_node_id = from_node.node_id
       JOIN nodes AS to_node 
            ON arcs.to_node_id = to_node.node_id;")

 arc_id from_node_id to_node_id node_label node_label
1      1            1          2          a          a
2      2            2          3          a          b
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to agree with @agstudy.  But in base R you just do this in two `merge` steps:

```
foo = merge(arcs, nodes, by.x='from_node_id', by.y='node_id')
bar = merge(foo, nodes, by.x='to_node_id', by.y='node_id')

bar
#   to_node_id from_node_id arc_id node_label.x node_label.y
# 1          2            1      1            a            a
# 2          3            2      2            a            b
```

You can rename accordingly.  If you use the `data.table` package and perform this merge with keyed data.tables it will be very fast.

Comment: Justin and @agstudy, this is not exactly what I was looking for but can you maybe help me clarify my question?
I know how to create a new data.frame, but it wouldn't act as a view, as then if e.g. a `node_label` changes, it has to be changed _both_ on tables node and arc. I need to somehow control the data integrity.

Comment: if you're asking me, I would say if a `node_label` changes you'll have to run the merge commands again.